# i want to change workflow status based on jenkins build with project name and status

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jira, jenkins-cli

I want to change workflow status based on jenkins build with project name and status. can anyone please help me out on this. I am able to do as below:    with story-id

```
def transitionInput = [transition: [id: '41']]

jiraTransitionIssue idOrKey: 'MSDP-198', input: transitionInput, site:  'JIRA'
```

but I need to list story id based on project name and status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

success {
script {

```
                    def searchResults = jiraJqlSearch jql: "PROJECT = 'MSDP' and status = 'READY FOR STAGING DEPLOYMENT' and type = 'Story'", site: 'JIRA'
                    def issues = searchResults.data.issues
                        for (i = 0; i <issues.size(); i++) {
                    def result = jiraGetIssue idOrKey: issues[i].key, site: 'JIRA'
                    
                    def transitionInput = [transition: [id: '41']]                  
                    def statuses = jiraGetProjectStatuses idOrKey: 'MSDP', site: 'JIRA'
                    responce = jiraTransitionIssue idOrKey: issues[i].key, input: transitionInput, site: 'JIRA' 
                        }
                }       
    } }
```